# Wildfly 16, the anotation @JsonIgnore doesn't work

Tags: java, json, rest, wildfly

I use wildfly 1-, and I implement a web service rest.

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Promotion implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String acronyme;
    private String intitule;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Etudiant> etudiants = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany
    private List<Module> modules; 
    public Promotion() {}
    public Promotion(String titre,String acronyme) {
        this.intitule = titre;
        this.acronyme = acronyme;
        etudiants = new ArrayList<Etudiant>();
    }
    .......... etc
}

@Path(value="/promotions")
public class RestServicePromotion {
    @Inject
    private MetierItf metier;

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public List<Promotion> lireTousPromotion() {
        System.out.println(metier.lireTousPromotion());
        return metier.lireTousPromotion();
    }
    .... etc
}
```

When I want to call the méthod lireTousPromotion(), I have the exception :

> Exception handling request to
>    /7EtudiantPromotionPresentationTout/rest/promotions:
>    org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException:
>    org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: entite.Promotion.modules, could not initialize proxy - no Session

I don't know how I can don't srialyse the modules fields. The @JsonIgnore doesn't be set.
See you

Answer (score 0):

Try using `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient` annotation for `Promotion#modules` field.

More information: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html